# PostgreSQL vacuum duration on a big table

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I have a very big table in my postgreSQL (over 300 million rows) that has never been vacuumed. Yesterday I tried a vacuum and analyze (not a full one) and it took about 7 hours to complete. Will it take 7 hours if I do it every day, or will the duration become smaller due to frequent maintenance?

Comment: Why was it never vacuumed? You should really (I mean really) enable auto-vacuum.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't specified your PostgreSQL version it's hard to answer. `VACUUM` has been improved in many ways on newer versions.

Presuming you're on 9.0 or 9.1 - so you don't need a `max_fsm_pages` setting, you have the improved `VACUUM FULL`, you have the visibility map, etc - then subsequent `VACUUM` operations should be quite fast. However, you should not be doing them.

Turn autovaccum on. Set it to run frequently. If this table is updated a lot, set autovaccum to process it more often. Vaguely modern PostgreSQL versions work best with lots of very frequent vacuum runs.